# Windows Update Center gives me error C0000022

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-activation

I have already started to think that it wasn't a good idea to format my PC on my own, so this is the issues I'm facing right now.

Like 2 weeks ago I could easily use the Windows update services,but now it gives me this error.

I tried to find solutions online,but didn't find any way which would help in my case.

This is the error I get:

[image]

And by the way,I don't know maybe the 2 are connected, I have also this issue:

[image]

Sorry for the Russian,it says that the Windows activation status is unavailable. I need to use the update services so that I can install SQL Server Management with its updates.

About installing SQL Management, this is what I get:

[image]

So I'm not sure maybe if I proceed with the installation in the future I'll get other errors.

Actually I didn't install any security update or any AntiVirus.
After doing the SFC/SCANNOW I didn't get any error:

[image]

It says Windows Resource Security didn't detect any (i don't know the translation of the rest of the sentence,sorry).

Comment: You don't need to use Windows Updates to install the current version of SQL Server Management.  What was the last security update that was installed?  What are the results from `SFC /SCANNOW`, please provide any errors from the relevant log file that is created, and updated your question.

Comment: I updated it,Check it out,please.

Comment: Your issue does indeed appear to be related to the activation status of Windows.  You didn't indicate what the last security update that was installed was.  I am going to guess this is a firewall/proxy issue.

Comment: So,could you please indicate what I'm suppose to do?.I really don't remember whether I installed any security update or not,but if I do remember well, I didn't

Comment: You can edit your question and indicate which update was last installed and when it was installed (Update History).  If you are using a proxy and/or know you are behind a firewall you should contact your IT Administrator.

Comment: You can also run winver and give us the full version number and any sub numbers. This can at least tell us the service pack and major patch level some times.